# Android video simulator

Tags: android, video, media, simulator, recording

I am new to Android development.

I have a requirement to record video through front and back cameras of android device. The default Android simulator doesn't support this video recording.

Please tell me how to run and test the video recording. Tell me if there are any simulators available.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean recording from both cameras at the same time?

Comment: Generally the emulator is not the best to develop with videos, as it's not very stable. Better to have a real device, especially if you have two cams in your device/specs.

Comment: yes, recording from both cameras at the same time:
and also, simulator to test them..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **Android Virtual Device** in Eclipse that supports Camera Input. I found this on [how to simulate app with media recorder(video) on avd(emulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299132/how-to-simulate-app-with-media-recordervideo-on-avdemulator), you can refer it for more details.