# how to simulate app with media recorder(video) on avd(emulator)

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device, android-mediarecorder

How to simulate video media recorder on android virtual device. I have tried to run an application that just capture videos with the guide:Building a Camera App http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have basic knowledge of android and eclipse. You have to create an **Android Virtual Device** in Eclipse that supports Camera Input. Depending on your needs, you have to enable Front Camera and/or Back Camera. When you start your application with some sort of camera preview it uses the webcam of your computer to show you live camera data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I already done it, my question was if I can run application that recorders video with media recorder on emulator(in the android developer site it says:"Note: Currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator."http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html